# Why don't raw pointer in vector become nullptr?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, raw-pointer

I want to dynamically-allocate an `int` and then push the corresponding pointer into the vector. After use, I  set to `nullptr` all the elements of vector, but original pointer doesn't become `nullptr`.

Why does this happen?

```
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    int* intPtr = new int(1);
    printf("%p¥n",intPtr); //(a)

    std::vector<int*> ptrVec;
    ptrVec.push_back(intPtr);

    for(auto* ptr : ptrVec)
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = nullptr; 
        printf("%p¥n",ptr); // (b) =>(nil)　 as expected.
    }

    printf("%p¥n",intPtr); //(c) is same with (a), opposite to my expect:(nil)
}
```

Comment: *but original pointer don't become nullptr* -- Because you didn't set the original pointer to nullptr.  C++ doesn't work in the way you thought it would -- you have two different pointer *variables* -- you need to manage all of them separately.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mean that a pointer in vector element and a original pointer is different?

Comment: *"I set nulptr to elements of vecotr, but original pointer don't become nullptr."* -- What behavior would you expect if the type was something other than a pointer? If you had a vector of `int`, initialized `int num = 1;`, pushed this onto the vector, then set the elements of the vector to `0`, would you expect `num` to be set to `0` also? Why would you expect a pointer to behave differently?

Comment: The `std::vector` stores *copies*.  If you need to see this, print out the [addresses](https://godbolt.org/z/qqMT6nMex).  See that they are *not* the same variable?

Comment: *"I set nullptr to elements of vector,"* -- No, you do not. After your loop, try printing out `ptrVec[0]`. It still stores the same pointer address as `intPtr`.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know `num` don't become 0 when I had a vector of `int` because it is copied when pushback. But, I don't know well the behavior when I had a vector of `int*`.  According to your comment, vector of `int*` behave as same as vector of `int`,right?

Comment: *Yes, I know num don't become 0 when I had a vector of int because it is copied when pushback.* -- So why would pointers be any different?  The vector doesn't automatically say "hey, I have a pointer, so do things differently".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I checked addresses original pointer and a element of vector, but they showed same addresses.

Comment: No, you didn't do what I suggested.  I printed out the **address of the pointer**, not the pointer value.  Look closely at the linked code in the comment I made.  Look at a simpler example: `int main() { int *p1; int *p2; int x = 10; *p1 = &x; *p2 = &x;  p1 = nullptr; }`.  Do you expect `p2` to be `nullptr` just because `p1` was set to `nullptr`?

Comment: BTW, your code is a prime example of why `std::shared_ptr` exists.  A program that has multiple pointers pointing to the same object, that program has to micromanage *all* of those separate pointer variables, making it very easy to miss one and not know the pointed-to object has been deleted.  There are still "old" C++ programs built this way that are full of bugs, all due to coding similar to yours.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I visited youe link, and I understand that `printf("%p¥n",ptr)` is printing value of pointer, `printf("%p¥n",&ptr)` is printing address of pointer.Thank you very much.
I used more complex object not `int`, so I can't realize `printf("%p¥n",ptr)` is printing value of pointer.

Comment: Fun fact: `auto* ptr` isn't the pointer in `ptrVec`, either. It's a copy.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh, OK.The following is OK?
`for(auto itr = ptrVec.begin(); itr!= ptrVec.end(); ++itr)
{
    delete *itr;
}`

Comment: @user4581301 In addition, Is the following also OK? `for(auto& ptr: ptrVec) { delete ptr;} `

Comment: It doesn't matter much. What you had was fine... unless you want something like `for(auto& ptr: ptrVec) { delete ptr; ptr = nullptr; }`, but that's useless in your case since you also want to `clear` the `vector` immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all!!

Just now, I understand `intPtr` and `ptrVec[0]`  points to same place, but they are different variables because intPtr is copied when push_back.

To prevent memory leak in this case, there are three ways.

1.Delete both elements of vector and original pointer .
But it is not safe for human mistake.

```
std::vector<int*> ptrVec;
{
    int* intPtr = new int(1);
    ptrVec.push_back(intPtr);
}

for(auto itr = ptrVec.begin(); itr!=ptrVec.end(); ++itr)
{
    delete *itr; 
}
ptrVec.clear();
```

2. New raw pointer when push_back directly. You only have to delete elements of vector.

```
std::vector<int*> ptrVec;
ptrVec.push_back(new int(1));

for(auto itr = ptrVec.begin(); itr!=ptrVec.end(); ++itr)
{
    delete *itr; 
}
ptrVec.clear();
```

3. Use shared_ptr

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> ptrVec;
ptrVec.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1));

ptrVec.clear();
```

Comment: Unless you have better reason you should use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thank you. In this case, I have to use a raw pointer for ORACLE procedure use.

Comment: If you need to delete the pointer later, you should use `unique_ptr` and pass the raw pointer elsewhere using `unique_ptr::get`. Only when you actually have shared ownership (approx. equivalent to "more than one place in your code may need to delete the same pointer") should you use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why bother calling `ptrVec.clear();`? There should be no reason to have any code later that looks at the value of `ptrVec`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thank you for your advise. I'll try to use unique_ptr::get instead of raw pointer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, there are no user after looking at the value of ptrVec, as you said. But for safety, I call `ptrVec.clear()` to prevent anyone use elements of vector.

Comment: Your first way has undefined behaviour, since it (effectively) does `delete intPtr` twice.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your commnent. I fixed the first source code.

Comment: @sparrow But it doesn't prevent anyone from using `ptrVec`. They could still dereference it and cause your code to crash. And if no code is ever supposed to access it, making that access more safe will just make it less likely that you will detect the access that wasn't supposed to happen. This is extra code to make your program worse.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm sorry but could you explain me in detail about**They could still dereference it and cause your code to crash.**?

Comment: Note: You can often use smart pointers even when the API wants a raw pointer because the smart pointer gives you access to the raw pointer it manages. If you need to provide a `vector` of raw pointers, then you're stuck. In that case I recommend considering 2 `vector`s: one of smart pointers to ensure proper-and-easy release of the pointed-at objects and one of raw pointers for the API to consume.

Comment: @sparrow If you dereference a null pointer, your code will likely crash. So setting the pointer to null doesn't guarantee that it's safe to access it. If the design decision is that the value of the pointer should never be accessed, there's no reason to set it to any particular value. But if you were going to set it to a value, NULL is not a particular good one because it may hide bugs if the code tests for NULL.